# Cannot print own data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

**Please read my problem below, after the bold text, before taking your time to scrutinize this code. I don't want to waste your time if you can't answer this.**

Okay. I have created my own data type within Haskell. It is

```
data Dialogue= Choice String [(String, Dialogue)] 
            | Action String Event
  -- deriving (Show)
```

Note the commented out 'deriving (Show)' which is important for my problem below.

I have a function named dialogue defined as

```
dialogue:: Game -> Dialogue -> IO Game
dialogue (Game n p ps) (Action s e) = do 
   putStrLn s
   return (e (Game n p ps))
dialogue (Game n p ps) (Choice s xs) = do
  putStrLn s
  let ys = [ fst a | a <- xs ]
  let i = [1..length ys]
  putStrLn (enumerate 1 ys)
  str <- getLine
  if str `elem` exitWords
  then do
     return (Game n p ps)
  else do
     let c = read str::Int
     if c `elem` i 
     then do 
        let ds = [ snd b | b <- xs ]
        let d = ds !! c
        putStrLn $ show d
        return (Game n p ps)
     else do
        error "error"
```

My data type game is defined as

```
data Game = Game Node Party [Party] | Won 
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

And an Event is a type, defined by myself as

```
type Event = Game -> Game
```

**Now, this is where my problem occurs.** When I go to load this file within cmd and I have **not** included *deriving (Show)* within my data type Dialogue, I get the following error:

```
* No instance for (Show Dialogue) arising from a use of `show'
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `(show d)'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ (show d)
  In the expression:
    do let ds = ...
       let d = ds !! c
       putStrLn $ (show d)
       return (Game n p ps)
    |
120 |          putStrLn $ (show d)
```

It would seem to me that I need to include the *deriving (Show)* in order to be able to print this data type to the console. However, when I do include *deriving (Show)*, I get this error:

```
* No instance for (Show Event)
    arising from the second field of `Action' (type `Event')
    (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
  Possible fix:
    use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
      so you can specify the instance context yourself
* When deriving the instance for (Show Dialogue)
   |
85 |   deriving Show
```

I have spent quite a long time trying to find out why this might be happening. But I cannot find anywhere online that seems to document this particular problem.

Any help would be perfect, or even just a link to an appropriate explanation.

**Edit: ** My Event is a type synonym and so I cannot add *deriving Show* to this

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Event` has to have a `Show` instance for things containing it to be able to automatically derive `Show`. That probably means adding `deriving Show` to your `Event` definition.

Comment: His `Event` type is an alias and can not carry a deriving clause.  It is also a function so automatic deriving won't work.

Comment: How would you expect to print an `Event`? Functions can not be printed in general. Perhaps you could define your own custom `instance Show Dialogue` without relying on `Show Event`, e.g. by showing that as some generic string "<event>".

Answer (score 5):

`Event` as you have defined it is a function which has no sensible method to show.  How would you like to display this information?  One solution is to `import Text.Show.Functions`, which has an instance.

For example:

```
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> show (+ 1)
"<function>"
```

Another solution is to define your own show instance:

```
instance Show (a -> b) where
    show _ = "_"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
type Event = Game -> Game
data Dialogue= Choice String [(String, Dialogue)] 
            | Action String Event
  -- deriving (Show)
```

When compiler tries to derive `Show` for `Dialogue`, it has to `Show` an `Event` in the `Action` variant, but it can't — `Event` is a function, and functions don't get auto-derived `Show` instances.

You have to manually implement either `Show Event` or `Show Dialogue`. One way to implement `Show Dialogue` would be this:

```
instance Show Dialogue where
    show (Choice s ds) = " "  `intercalate`  ["Choice", show s, show ds]
    show (Action s e) = " "  `intercalate`  ["Action", show s]
```

Comment: You can also use `unwords` instead of `intercalate`.